# Git - pushing repository to heroku fails (java app)

Tags: java, git, heroku

Im building an app using OpenTripPlanner, and when I run the app locally with play run it runs fine but when I try to upload to heroku with git push heroku master it starts uploading fine but after a while it always ends with these errors:
[image: here]

Can someone help me? I've searched but i didn't find similar problems that could help me.

Comment: It seems to me that the root cause of the failure to push is actually the failure your Maven build.  So, maybe you should start by looking into that.

Comment: How to do that ? I have maven folder in my C local disk

Comment: Start by scrolling up in that window. There should be some helpful error messages higher up. You might also want to go through some of Heroku's introductory documentation as it relates to Java: https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/java-support

Comment: Console output is made of _text_. It should be shared _as text_, not as screenshots. Text can be copied and pasted into a text editor! Screenshots cannot :-(. Text can be efficiently searched! Screenshots cannot :-(. Text can be consumed by users of assistive technologies, like screenreaders! Screenshots cannot :-(. [Please give text the respect it deserves instead of banishing it to inaccessible image formats](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577).

Comment: It looks like `mvn install` is try to sign some jar files with gpg. That won't work on Heroku unless you've set up a gpg key. It's also probably unnecessary.